# I am getting an error while installing neat through pip

Tags: python, pip, neat

getting the following error when trying to install neat through pip:

C:\Windows\System32>pip install neat
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
Collecting neat
Using cached neat-0.4.1.tar.gz (88 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [1 lines of output]
error in neat setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)

just tried to install but instead got this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe the neat is not installed correctly ,
try this

```
pip install neat-python
```

also if this doesn't work maybe it's due to some spelling error try share the code

Comment: This was the right answer. It really was the problem in missing characters while installing. Correct command is pip install neat-python. I don't know if it is allowed but thanks for your answer. It helped a lot.